# Edit an account in Sugarcrm

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, sugarcrm

I am having trouble uploading a file, from a form to Sugarcrm.

I am using [this tutorial](http://techs.studyhorror.com/sugarcrm-python-rest-i-68), which states that the following code should update an account:

```
#2 - UPDATE AN EXISTING ENTRY
sugarcrm_conn= None

try:
    sugarcrm_conn = sugarcrm.Sugarcrm(url = sugarcrm_url, username = sugarcrm_user, password = sugarcrm_pass)
    print "Connected to sugar via rest"
except ValueError:
    print "cann't connect to " + sugarcrm_url
exit(1)

accounts = sugarcrm_conn.module('Accounts')
#we just show the first ten of them.
for account in accounts[:10]:
    account.setValue(['shipping_address_postalcode','email'],['4144','test@gmail.com'])
```

The problem I am having is that I get the error:

> Sugarcrm instance has no attribute 'module'

for the line

> Sugarcrm instance has no attribute 'module'

Have I missed something? To clarify, I can connect to Sugarcrm and have added Accounts, as well as displayed them.

Answer (score 0):

```
query = sugarcrm_conn['Accounts'].query()
results = query.filter(last_name_contains = 'example')
for account in results[:10]:
    print(' '.join(account['first_name','last_name']))
```

Comment: You should include explanations about the code and how to use it. A bare code is not sufficient for a good answer.

Comment: How does this even edit the account anyway? It looks to only be printing out the result set.